# Confusing about command with docker exec

Tags: docker

I am confused when I use commands with docker exec as below.

```
# docker exec -it testing cat /tmp/1.txt
1
...
# docker exec -it testing echo 2 >> /tmp/1.txt
# docker exec -it testing cat /tmp/1.txt
1
...
# docker exec -it testing /bin/sh -c "echo 2 >> /tmp/1.txt"
# docker exec -it testing cat /tmp/1.txt
1
2
```

When I use command echo without attaching with /bin/sh, it don't affect my file in container. Anyone, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a container , you file system is not the same .

**/tmp/** in your docker is not the same that the **/tmp/** on your system .

when you run

```
 docker exec -it testing /bin/sh -c "echo 2 >> /tmp/1.txt"
```

you run **sh** with one 2 parameter **-c** and **"echo 2 >> /tmp/1.txt"** , your sh is running inside the container

when you run

```
docker exec -it testing echo 2 >> /tmp/1.txt
```

you run **echo** with one parameter **2**  and ** '>> /tmp/1.txt'** is at the same context that your docker command so outside your container .